# WordPress on MAMP giving 'Error 500' with internet connection

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp, internet-connection

I have WordPress installed on a MAMP server.  After installing some plugins I suddenly got an 'Error 500' but only when my MacBook had wifi connected. 
Turning the wifi off fixes the issue, but turning it back on or uploading to a live server causes the issue to return.

After looking through the PHP log, I got:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file 
in /private/var/tmp/theme_temp_setupGlYc25 on line 2
```

and:

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 
'REQUEST_URI' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp- 
content/themes/THEME_NAME/functions.php on line 48
```

Uninstalling the plugins that I had recently installed did not fix the issue, nor did re-installing MAMP or moving the installation to a new localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from a WordPress plugin downloaded from an untrusted source.

On installing the plugin, it wrote a number of lines of code in the *functions.php* file within the theme I was using which was throwing the 'Error 500' as it tried to connect to a server at 'spekt.cc'.

By following the PHP log; googling the Parse error and PHP warning, I saw a post on Medium from someone saying a similar thing happened to them with WordPress attempting to connect to 'spekt.cc'.

Using 'ack' in Homebrew, I searched my WordPress directory and found the affected files. *(It had been installed on all themes within the directory)*

After removing this PHP code it had inserted and removing the affected plugin, my WordPress is working fine again.